# Convert RGB Color to HEX color

Tags: android, graphics, hex, rgb

I am taking a color from an `ImageView` using `OnTouchListener`.

Red, Green, Blue color code can be successfully obtained, but i cant convert RGB to HEX ..

example : my rgb values are
r:21

b:16

g:228

and curresponding hex color is #15e410.

i want get #15e410.  from r:21 ,b:16 ,g:228

```
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);             
                int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

                int hexa=  Color.rgb(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hexa ::"+hexa ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: `redValue+greenValue+blueValue` doesnt make sens

Comment: how can i solve?

Comment: `String.format("#%06X", pixel)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

Just use:

```
String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
```

This will convert all the Red, Green and Blue values to Hex String.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Avinash Happy to Help brother ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.toHexString(color);` to convert an integer to hex string.

Example:

```
int color = 0xff334433;
String hex = Integer.toHexString(color);
System.out.println(hex); // this prints - ff334433
```

Comment: color = 0xff334433;  how can get this value ,my rgb values are  r:21 b:16 g:228 and curresponding hex color is 15e410

Comment: No, it is just for example and can be any value. It can also be the value returned from the method `Color.rgb(21, 228, 16)`.

Comment: is it combination of r,g,b ?

Comment: Yes it is. By the way, first `ff` corresponds to alpha channel. For RGB color, it is always 255, i.e. FF in hex.

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution:**

```
Function RGBToHex(red As Integer, green As Integer, blue As Integer) As String
    Return String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", red, green, blue)
End Function
```

This function takes three integers as input (representing the red, green, and blue values of the color) and returns a string in the format "#RRGGBB" where RR, GG, and BB are the hexadecimal values of the red, green, and blue components of the color.

You can call this function by passing the red, green, and blue values of a color as arguments, like this:

```
Dim hexColor As String = RGBToHex(255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are sending wrong the parameters to the function String.format to get the hexColor.

Try this one:

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", redValued, greenValue, blueValue);
```

Comment: [your code result #0000FF  should be #FFFFFF](https://ideone.com/9r4xHY)

Comment: Yes, should be like that